# VBA - removing characters, digits

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Workbook with a column ("M", or "13") looking like this:

```
1.1 Residential - Bla bla bla<br>
1.1 Residential:  Bla bla bla<br>
1.2  - Residential  Bla bla bla<br>
2.2 - 1.3 Residential  Bla bla bla<br>
3.1 - Multi Residential  Bla bla bla<br>
etc..<br>
```

The old indexing nomenclature used by my client went from 1.1 to 3.3

I need to scrape this column and get rid of all these three digits, making whatever text that comes after them still appear within the cell.

Example:

```
Residential - Bla bla bla<br>
Residential:  Bla bla bla<br>
Residential  Bla bla bla<br>
Residential  Bla bla bla<br>
Multi Residential  Bla bla bla<br>
etc..
```

Comment: And what code have you tried already?

Comment: As I mentioned Jonnus, I'm quite a rookie in VBA. I have tried a lot of examples from the community here. The only problem is that the vast majority of those are for text. I am really lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it deletes numbers, period, hyphen, and space at the beginning of every cell in the M column. I only did 5, but change it to do any number of cells:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 5
  Dim j As Integer
  Dim value As String
  value = Range("M" & i)

  For j = 1 To Len(value)
    Select Case Mid(value, j, 1)
    Case 0 To 9
    Case "-"
    Case "."
    Case " "
    Case Else
      Exit For
    End Select
  Next
  Range("M" & i) = Mid(value, j, Len(value))
Next
```

If you prefer not worry about specifying the number of cells and let do all cells that contain a value like Jonnus answer, then you can try this:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Do Until Range("M" & i) = ""
  Dim j As Integer
  Dim value As String
  value = Range("M" & i)

  For j = 1 To Len(value)
    Select Case Mid(value, j, 1)
    Case 0 To 9
    Case "-"
    Case "."
    Case " "
    Case Else
      Exit For
    End Select
  Next
  Range("N" & i) = Mid(value, j, Len(value))
  i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: My very best cheers lads. The code blocks above do not generate any erros. However, all the 1.1, 1.2,.. 3.3, etc are still there and nothing changes. I reckon there must be something else. :/

Comment: I've done it in Excel with your sample data and it works like a charm. You said you tried Jonnus' answer "again" and it worked. Mine is almost the same it should work for you, so give it another shot. You can use his answer if you like, but my answer will work with any Language (not only English) and symbols in case your text start with one of those. Also my answer runs slightly faster because I didn't use like & regex.

Comment: I corrected my comment @racilhilan. It was actually your line that worked for me. I up-voted accordingly. (apologies, still getting the hang of the this). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the following code will loop through Column 13, looking at each cell in turn, finding the first alphabetic character, and stripping off all characters preceding it

```
Dim rowNum As Integer
Dim curValue as String

RowNum = 1

' Loop though all cells in the column until a blank one is found
Do While Cells(13, rowNum).Value <> ""

    ' Get the current value of the cell
    curValue = Cells(13, rowNum).Value

    ' Loop through all the characters until the first alpha character is 
    ' found, and save the index of this first character
    Dim x as Long
    For x = 1 to Len(curValue)
        sChar = Mid(curValue, x, 1)
        If sChar Like "[a-zA-z\)\(\[\]]" Then
            firstChar = x
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x

    ' Set the value of the cell to be the current value starting from 
    ' the first alpha character
    Cells(13, rowNum).Value = Right(curValue, Len(curValue) - x)

    ' Go to the next row
    rowNum = rowNum + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Cool idea to use `Value <> ""`. That can be a nice enhancement to my answer. As for the `Like "[a-zA-Z]"`, this is a bit assumption. It only works for English language and text cannot start with anything else such as a bracket.

Comment: I've updated the edges to include square brackets and braces (). Have a Google around regular expressions to find something that will do the job including non-English characters as its difficult to suggest something without knowing your precise requirements

Comment: Wait, @RacilHilan, I tried your code again and it worked! You're rock and roll mate. Jonnus, thanks a lot as well mate. My best cheers.

Comment: Fantastic. I was waiting until I got on my laptop before debugging it further. I'm pleased you've got there already. Please upvote/mark as answer to help people in the future who might have the same question